# Stripe node js api Issue with accepting T/C

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, stripe-payments

I am using cloud functions from firebase and node js to use the stripe api. The code to create a user works perfectly:

```
exports.createStripeCustomerOnUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

return stripe.accounts.create({
    type: 'custom',
    country: 'US',
    email: user.email
  }, (err, account) => {
    // asynchronously called
    if(err){
        console.log("ERROR" + err.message)
        return admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/stripeConnected`).set(false);

    }else{
        // success 
        const accountID = `${account["id"]}`
        console.log("account ID: " + accountID)
       return stripe.accounts.update(
            accountID,
            {
             metadata: {internal_id:42},
                // tos_acceptance: {
                //   date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                //   ip: request.connection.remoteAddress // Assumes you're not using a proxy
                // },

           }
           ).then((account) => {

                 admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/stripeConnectId`).set(accountID); 
                return admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/stripeConnected`).set(true); 
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                return console.log(error)
            })

    }

  });
```

});

The line involving the the stripe.accounts.update is where I would like to accept the T/C on behalf of my user. The documentation on stripe provides an example of this, however I get an error when using there example:

```
'request is not defined
at stripe.accounts.create'
```

Here is a link to their example( see under Indicating acceptance on their Stripe account):

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/updating-accounts

I commented out where I use their example in my code. What could be going wrong??

Comment: What version of the Stripe node library are you using? When I try to run this with node, it works just as you'd expect https://pastebin.com/HQBs5sWi

Comment: I ended up getting it to work ,turns out I had issues with my IP address since im using firebase cloud functions @duck